# Combinations of different numbers and their relations

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I have written a simple program in c# to generate different combinations of numbers in a set of five.
The combinations generated will be stored in int array. It will be read five by five.

```
int[] number = new int[no_of_combination];
```

I want to find out how many numbers are repeated in these combinations.
e.g {1 2 3 4 5} and {3 4 5 6 7} have three repeated numbers and they are {3 4 5}

My approach is that compare every single combination with all other combinations.
For n combinations, there will be n(n-1)/2 comparisons. The result(number of repeated numbers and corresponding values of them) will be stored in object arrays.
If n is large, say, 100000, the number of operations will be extremely large. This uses up large amount of memory to store the result.

```
    int[] init = new int[6]; // 6 for no repeat,1,2,3,4 and 5, init counting the number of combinations in each repeated number group
    RepeatedSet[,] S = new  RepeatedSet[6,number.Length*number.Length];
    for(int i=0;i<number.Length-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<number.Length;j++)
        {
            int no_of_repeated_number = 0;
            int a = i, b = j;                
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                 // counting number of repeated numbers
                 for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
                 {
                      if (n[a, k] == n[b, l])
                      {
                          no_of_repeated_number++;
                      }
                 }
                 int[] repeated_number_set = new int[no_of_repeated_number];
                 int count = 0;
                 // putting the repeated numbers value into array
                 for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                 {
                      for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
                      {
                          if (n[a, k] == n[b, l])
                          {
                              repeated_number_set[count] = n[a,k];
                              count++;
                          }
                      }
                 }
                 // create objects to store the infomation
                 S[no_of_repeated_number, init[no_of_repeated_number]] = new RepeatedSet(a,b,repeated_number_set,repeated_number_set.Length);
                 init[no_of_repeated_number]++;  
            }   
        }
    {
```

Class RepeatedSet :

```
class RepeatedSet
    {
        int combinationA = 0; // sequence no. of combination A
        int combinationB = 0; // sequence no. of combination B
        int[] repeat = new int[0];

        public RepeatedSet(int a, int b, int[] r, int size)
        {
            combinationA = a;
            combinationB = b;
            repeat = new int[size];
            repeat = r;
        }

        public int getcombinationA()
        {
            return this.combinationA;
        }

        public int getcombinationB()
        {
            return this.combinationB;
        }

        public int[] getRepeatedSet()
        {
            return this.repeat;
        }
```

My question: Is there any better way to complete the task without intensive operations of comparison?

Comment: You should post all your code. Ie what is `RepeatedSet`and `number`, etc.

Comment: RepeatedSet class added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve your problem is to use a Dictionary, keys being the numbers in your sets of five, and values being the times the values appear in those sets (assuming that each number occurs at most once in a set of five).

Iterating over the keys of the Dictionary, you can easily determine whether

- a number is unique over all sets of five: the repeat count equals 1
- a number occurs in all sets of five: the repeat count equals the number of sets
- a number occurs more than once but not in all sets

**Later**

Only a few pointers.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

To count another number:

```
int count;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(number, out count)){
  dictionary[number] = count + 1;
} else {
  dictionary[number] = 1;
}
```

To investigate the result

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> pair in dictionary){
  int number = pair.Key;
  int count = pair.Value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: How to create such a dictionary which will include all the possibilities of the number combinations?